# Fade Out Background Overlay on Mouse Over

Tags: css, jquery-animate, overlay

Im Working on this Page: http://gpt.hernan.org/gpnew/v1%20(Referrals%20hover).html
When hovering on Referrals Button, a Background Overlay appears, I need it to gradually apear. Maybe some Fade in or out animation.

I'm using this script to make the Overlay run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
   $('#coins').on('mouseenter', function(){
          var w = $(window).width();
          var h = $(window).height();
      $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').
               addClass('overlay').css({ 'width': w, 'height': h });
      }).on('mouseleave', function(){
      $('.overlay').remove();
      })                
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `CSS` only ;)

Using `CSS3 Transition`, you can specify for each property you want to transition, n1 seconds lenght, after n2 seconds of an optional delay (and the type of transition, but it is not interesting here, default is ease).

By the way, `CSS3 Transition` doesn't work with `Display` nor `Visibility`; you will have to use tricks like `height: 0px;`, or moving out of the visible area, or changing the z-index, or, the best choice in your case, using Opacity.

Start with `opacity: 0;`, do transition to `opacity: 1;` in `hover`.

In your case:

```
.button-hover ul ul {
  min-width: 449px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80%;
  z-index: 598;

  transition: all 1s ease 0s; /* new */
  opacity: 0; /* new */
  /* visibility: hidden; -> removed */
}
```

And in `:hover` instead of

```
.button-hover ul li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

use

```
.button-hover ul li:hover > ul{
    opacity: 1;
}
```